# For what $n$, is $S_{n}$ a homomorphic image of $S_{n+1}$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group of $n$-elements.

If there is a surjective homomorphism from $S_{n+1}$ to $S_{n}$, then there must be a normal subgroup of order $n+1$ of $S_{n+1}$ given by the kernel of the homomorphism. If $n+1$ is prime, this subgroup is cyclic. It must be generated by a cycle of length $n+1$.

But the subgroup cannot be a normal subgroup in general. Thus for some $n$, there isn't such a surjective homomorphism. Hence the question:

> For what values of $n$, does there exists a surjective homomorphism $S_{n+1} \to S_n$?

Comment: is $S_{n}$ the symmetric group?

Comment: There is always either the zero homomorphism or the sign homomorphism composed with any inclusion of a transposition. Do you mean a *surjective* homomorphism? If so, the simplicity of $A_n$ gives $n \le 3$ and I think all of these values of $n$ work. The surjection $S_4 \to S_3$ is given, for example, by the action of $S_4$ by conjugation on its elements of cycle type $(2, 2)$.

Comment: As far as I know, and I'm often reminded that that's not that far, there's no such thing as "homomorphic groups".

Comment: Why is the assumption that the homomorphism is surjective "of course"? As has been pointed out "homomorphic to" does not have any standard meaning, so it is hard to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

Let's let $\phi\colon S_{n+1}\to S_n$ be a surjective homomorphism. Then, as you said the kernel of $\phi$ must be a normal subgroup of $S_{n+1}$, and $|\text{ker }\phi|=n+1$.

Luckily, the normal subgroups of the symmetric groups are well-understood. Here is a [proof](https://planetmath.org/normalsubgroupsofthesymmetricgroups) that the only normal subgroup of $S_n$ is $A_n$, when $n\geq 5$. (That proof relies on the knowledge that the alternating groups $A_n$ are simple for $n\neq 4$, a proof of which can be found [here](http://www.pitt.edu/%7Egmc/ch1/node4.html).) Clearly, for $n+1\geq 5$, the alternating group $A_{n+1}\leq S_{n+1}$ will be far too large to be our kernel; therefore, we only have to check the cases $n=1,2,3$.

$n=1$ is the easiest; $S_1$ is trivial, so the trivial homomorphism $\phi_{id}\colon S_2\to S_1$ works.

For $n=2$, we can easily see that the sign homomorphism, which sends even homomorphisms to the identity and odd homomorphisms to the transpositions $(1\ 2)$, will do nicely as our homomorphism $\phi\colon S_3\to S_2$.

$n=3$ is far more interesting; $A_4$ is actually non-simple, and $S_4$ has a normal subgroup $H$ that is isomorphic to the Klein $4$-group. This subgroup, it turns out, is perfect for our kernel. A description of this homomorphism $\phi:S_4\to S_3$ is left as an exercise to the reader :-)